# Passing data from dojo screen to react screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dojo

We are in the process of migrating screens from dojo to React. There is one instance however where i open a new window in React when a checkbox is checked on dojo screen. 
My question is how am i going to transfer data from dojo screen to new react screen and then back to dojo when fields in react screen are populated. 
Eg. A, B on dojo screen is passed to React window and accordingly data is shown based on which used chooses C, D and now C, D needs to be sent back to dojo screen
Ultimately both of them are js. Dojo being a toolkit and React being a framework. I am sure this is a doable scenario but question is how.

i can understand data handling solely on a dojo screen or on a react screen. I have been lost on it for many hours and will appreciate any help possible

Edit : Is localstorage of the webbrowser a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass data between windows.